# Signature and isotropic vectors of a simmetrical dot product.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Lets'say i have this matrix wich is the rappresentative of my dot product:

A:=$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &-1  &0 \\ 
-1 &1  &-1 \\ 
 0 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

if i want to find the signature of the dot product linked to this matrix i just need to find the signature of the matrix itself?

If yes i have found $p_A$=$-x^3+3x^2-x-1$ so thanks to the Cartesio's rule the signature is $(2,1,0)$.

Now i want to know if there are isotropic vectors and if yes i need to write one of them. So i need to find a vector $X:<X,X>=0$.

<,> is defined by the matrix and X will be a generic $R^3$ vector like $X=(x_1, x_2, x_3)$

Composing my dot product i find:

$<X,X>=0=x^2_1+x^2_2+x^2_3-(x_1 x_2)^2-(x_2 x_3)^2$

I see that for $X=(0,0,0)$ i have $<X,X>=0$.

Is $X:=(0,0,0)$ one isotropic vector? There are others? If yes there is an easy way to find them?

Is my result correct? I am doing it right?

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is symmetric and has signature (2,1), A induces a Lorentz product, meaning that we have a different type of dot product
$$\vec{x} \circ \vec{y} = \vec{x}^t A \vec{y}$$ 
In particular, "$\circ$" is not an inner product since it is possible to have $\vec{x} \circ \vec{x} =0$ for nonzero $\vec{x}$. To find such vectors, this is equivalent to solving
$$(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2-y^2 = 0$$
for $\vec{x} = (x,y,z)$
This is equivalent to finding vectors on the "light cone":
[image: Light Cone]

In particular, the vector $(0,1,1)$ (and all multiples thereof) has square length $0$.

Comment: What the damn? Im studyig for geometry 1, never seen light cones, Lorrentz products and things like that. My procedure is essentially wrong? (at least the signature is correct i understand). And how you find this $(x−y)^2+(y−z)^2−y^2=0$ ?

Comment: Your procedure is right. You're just approaching the problem algebraically. If you write out $\vec{x}^t A \vec{x}$ and factor, you get the above equation, which is the equation of the cone pictured above.

Comment: oh... ...and sorry if im so bad but...   ...how can i find the solution of a single equation with 3 variables? just try some substituction? Oh, and $(0,0,0)$ is valid as isotropic vector?

Comment: Ok, 0 is obviusly valid, those cones starts from it...